# Integral of $\sec \theta$ with a small imaginary part

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

When I plug

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{d\theta}{\cos\theta - i a}$$

into Mathematica, it quickly spits out

$$I = \frac{2 \pi i}{\sqrt{a^2+1}} (-1)^K$$

where

$$K = \left\lfloor \frac{-2 \arg (a-i)+\arg \left(a^2+1\right)+\pi }{2 \pi }\right\rfloor.$$

I've tried to reproduce this with no luck. It looks like an application of the residue theorem because of the $2\pi i$ factor. **How do I derive this result for $I$?**

A second related question: I'm having a hard time interpreting this result. For example, it seems to suggest that $\int_0^{2\pi}\sec\theta d\theta = 2\pi i $. **In what sense is this true?** It seems that $\int_0^{2\pi}\sec\theta d\theta$ is either zero or ill-defined.

Any comments are appreciated (including suggested resources that I should consult for either question), thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the Mathematica result exactly, but 1/(cos(x)-a) has a perfectly reasonable antiderivative that you can just evaluate over interval (0, 2pi)

Comment: ... with careful attention paid to branch cuts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $z=e^{iθ}$ then $\cos θ=\frac12(z+z^{-1})$, $dz=iz\,dθ$ so that
$$
I=\int_{|z|=1}\frac{-2i\,dz}{z^2+1-2iaz}
=-2i\int_{|z|=1}\frac{dz}{(z-ia)^2+1+a^2}
$$
The point $z=ia(1-\sqrt{1+a^{-2}})$ is the pole of the integrand inside the unit circle, so that by residue theory
$$
I=2\pi i·\frac{-2i}{-2ia\sqrt{1+a^{-2}}}=\frac{2\pi i}{a\sqrt{1+a^{-2}}}
$$
For real $a$, this simplifies in the obvious way, however the above expression is also valid for complex $a\ne 0$, where the square root is the variant that has a positive real part whenever possible.

Answer (score 2):

Integrate as follows

\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\cos\theta - i a}d\theta
=& \int_0^{2\pi}\frac{\cos\theta +ia }{\cos^2\theta +a^2}d\theta
= \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{4ia }{\cos^2\theta +a^2}d\theta\\
= &\frac{4i}a\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{d(\tan\theta) }{\tan^2\theta+\frac{1+a^2}{a^2}}=\frac{2i\pi}{\sqrt{1+a^2}}
\end{align}